# What's mean "identical to -e" when I use this command: ps -A?

Tags: ps

I want to know what this mean.

`ps -A` → Select all processes. Identical to -e.

What's mean "Identical to -e."?

Answer (score 4):

It simply means that the command can be either typed as `ps -A` or `ps -e` and will produce the same result.

Answer (score 3):

If means that

```
ps -A
```

and

```
ps -e
```

are the same command.

It is a compatibility issue: in older nonstandartized UNIX systems there were many implementations of commands, and sometimes they used different options for the same things.

Answer (score 1):

From [`man ps`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/ps.1.html):

> ```
>    -A     Select all processes.  Identical to -e.
>
>    [...]
>
>    -e     Select all processes.  Identical to -A.
> ```

So, these two options, `-A` and `-e`, are identical (equivalent) and produce identical results when these are used inside of `ps` command and their job is (no matter what option, `-A` or `-e`, you choose to use) to select all processes when `ps` is invoked.

Now, what ***identical*** means? From http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/identical:

> 1. similar or alike in every way: *The two cars are identical except for their license plates.*
> 2. being the very same; selfsame: *This is the identical room we stayed in last year.*
> 3. agreeing exactly: *identical opinions.*
>
> Synonyms: congruous, congruent, equal, matching.